# What happens if the super class returns a different object?

Tags: objective-c, xcode

So, what happens if [super init] returns a different object?

```
self = [super init];
```

Comment: What do you mean exactly? Different from what?

Answer (score 0):

You use it regardless of its value.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: @UwePlonus Yeah it does; garbage in, garbage out.